# What does it mean by Gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android-sdk

**Gradle** is not an ordinary English word. Then, what does it mean in Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the name of a build system for Java programs. Gradle is the build system currently recommended by Google for building Android apps.

To learn more, check out the top item of [this list](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=gradle).

Answer (score 0):

I just learned about **Gradle** an hour ago. It reminds me of "Cradle to Grave" which I thought was a good name for Software Project Manager. After reading your question I googled it's meaning and in December 2011 the [inventor](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-is-gradle-called-gradle/3226) said:

> My original idea was to call it Cradle. The disadvantages of that name
> were:
>
> - to diminutive
> - not very unique
>
> As Gradle is using Groovy for the DSL I went down the G-road and
> thought about calling it Gradle. Everyone I asked liked it so that
> became the official name. That was about 4 years ago. I’m still very
> happy with the name.

So from the author we can gleam the **Gradle** was invented in 2007.

### More to the point

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) we learn:

> Gradle is an open-source build automation system that builds upon the
> concepts of Apache Ant and Apache Maven and introduces a Groovy-based
> domain-specific language (DSL) instead of the XML form used by Apache
> Maven for declaring the project configuration.[1](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-is-gradle-called-gradle/3226) Gradle uses a
> directed acyclic graph ("DAG") to determine the order in which tasks
> can be run.
>
> Gradle was designed for multi-project builds, which can grow to be
> quite large. It supports incremental builds by intelligently
> determining which parts of the build tree are up to date; any task
> dependent only on those parts does not need to be re-executed.
>
> The initial plugins are primarily focused on Java,[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) Groovy and Scala
> development and deployment, but more languages and project workflows
> are on the roadmap.

In computer old school terms we can say it only compiles objects that have changed in a project when some source code has changed. Thereby saving total compile time from hours to minutes.

In layman's terms we can say it's a project manager that knows all the bits and pieces required to build something.